# What is the horizontal scrolling effect in WPF/Silverlight called?

Tags: wpf

I am starting out creating a prototype of a WPF fullscreen kiosk app and was wondering what is the effect of the scrolling city names used in the Weather Station app? http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/weatherstation/

Also are there any particular sites you get good tutorials and info on WPF/Silverlight? I've been working in .Net since it came out and most tutorials I find are super simplistic or at level 99...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had totally forgot about this question until reading another  [WPF article about making your app stand out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/07/11/creating-metro-style-apps-that-stand-out-from-the-crowd.aspx) when the author mentioned "panning".